# What was Wilson's mistake in the 1918 Congressional election?

Tags: united-states, 20th-century, political-history, us-congress

Keynes writes in *[The Economic Consequences of the Peace](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15776/15776-h/15776-h.htm)* that

> The [President](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodrow_Wilson)'s mistaken policy over the Congressional election had
>   weakened his personal position in his own country, and it was by no
>   means certain that the American public would support him in a position
>   of intransigency.

Presumably these are the 1918 midterm elections.

What mistake is Keynes referring to?

Answer (score 5):

Apparently the mistake was an electoral appeal that urged Americans to vote Democratic because a vote for Republicans would

> ". . . be interpreted on the other side of the water as a repudiation of my leadership." .

This achieved the opposite of the desired effect, losing the election for the Democrats, as the letter was (correctly) perceived as an unwarranted slight on the Republicans' patriotism.

Source: http://www.canadafreepress.com/index.php/article/29553